# Python and java AES/ECB/PKCS5 encryption

Tags: java, python, encryption

JAVA VERSION:

```
public class EncryptUtil {
    public static String AESEncode(String encodeRules, String content) {
        try {
            KeyGenerator keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
            keygen.init(128, new SecureRandom(encodeRules.getBytes()));
        SecretKey original_key = keygen.generateKey();
        byte[] raw = original_key.getEncoded();
        SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] byte_encode = content.getBytes("utf-8");
        byte[] byte_AES = cipher.doFinal(byte_encode);
        return new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(byte_AES));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
       return null;
   }

}
```

When i run this code:

```
System.out.println(EncryptUtil.AESEncode("1234567812345678", python&java"));
```

I've got:

```
V5FFUgDi7VZaJ0qGzDISoA==
```

PYTHON VERSION:

```
import base64

from Crypto.Cipher import AES

BLOCK_SIZE = 16  # Bytes
pad = lambda s: s + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE) * \
            chr(BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE)
unpad = lambda s: s[:-ord(s[len(s) - 1:])]


class AESUtil:
    __BLOCK_SIZE_16 = BLOCK_SIZE_16 = AES.block_size

    def __init__(self, key):
         self.key = key

    def encrypt(self, raw):
        raw = pad(raw)
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_ECB)
        return base64.b64encode(cipher.encrypt(raw))

    def decrypt(self, enc):
        enc = base64.b64decode(enc)
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_ECB)
        return unpad(cipher.decrypt(enc))
```

I know java use AES/ECB/PKCS#5 by default, but when I run the `encrypt` method ：

```
cipher_text = AESUtil("1234567812345678").encryt('python&java')
```

got:`b'3mjygpK1d7ThCRK98ssZhA=='`

The pad and unpad i found them in Googles.
How do I edit my PYTHON code make the cipher_text equals JAVA encryption.
Can somebody know how to fix it?

Comment: @e4c5 without IV specified, seems the ECB is used. Indeed the best practice is to explicitly specify the mode `Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/Pkcs5Padding");`

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same key? (could you print encoded value of the keys used in Java and in Python?)  (using the "encodeRules" is very strange IMHO)

Comment: @gusto oops, getInstance("AES/ECB/Pkcs5Padding"); was what I intended to paste!

Comment: Yes i'm sure, both key are '1234567812345678' @gusto2

Comment: I am sure they are not (please print the `raw` variable, that's the key). Providing `1234567812345678` as a parameter, the Java app (please read the code) creates a new random with the static seed which is not random, but definitely not bytes you expect. If you want to use the key as it is, you may use `byte[] raw = encodeRules.getBytes()`  (assuming the string has 16 bytes). Please note your implementation is far from secure for encryption (ECB mode, simple key, ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use different encryption keys

In Java

> System.out.println(EncryptUtil.AESEncode("1234567812345678", "python&java"));

See the code:

```
KeyGenerator keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
keygen.init(128, new SecureRandom(encodeRules.getBytes()));
SecretKey original_key = keygen.generateKey();
byte[] raw = original_key.getEncoded();
```

If you print the `raw` key, you will get `fd839759956ba4a47922e8ee7c902f52` (HEX encoded), that's the encryption key

If you would like to use the provided key directy, you should use

```
byte[] raw = encodeRules.getBytes(); 
// (assuming encodeRules has 16 bytes)
```

> How do I edit my PYTHON code make the cipher_text equals JAVA encryption

That's tricky..  you may have a look [how SecureRandom works](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/47871/how-securely-random-is-oracles-java-security-securerandom), but IMHO it's easier to fix the Java implementation to create a key you expect

Regardless that I'd consider the implementation not secure enough - using ECB and simple key.

Comment: you're right,I make a mistake ,  I thought '1234567812345678' is the key, the java is my colleague‘s code ,thank you  very much

Comment: @ZeeBmChan: in that case tell your collegue that using SecureRandom is not how passwords are converted into keys (the implementation may change in different versions). Using a cryptographic hash or PBKDF is much more feasible (safe).