# python CFB decryption appending random chars at the end

Tags: python, encryption, aes, decode

i have a simple case , encrypt in golang and decrypt in python, I am using the AES.CFB for it as I don't have much knowledge about the modes and stuff.

for encryption in Golang

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/aes"
    "crypto/cipher"
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

var iv = []byte("mb13KcoviZizvYhp")

func encodeBase64(b []byte) string {
    return base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(b)
}

func Encrypt(key, text string) string {
    block, err := aes.NewCipher([]byte(key))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    plaintext := []byte(text)
    cfb := cipher.NewCFBEncrypter(block, iv)
    ciphertext := make([]byte, len(plaintext))
    cfb.XORKeyStream(ciphertext, plaintext)
    return encodeBase64(ciphertext)
}

func main() {
    key := []byte("TfvY7I358yospfWKcoviZizOShpm5hyH")
    x := strings.TrimSpace(Encrypt(string(key), "hello world"))
    fmt.Println(x)

}
```

and For the decryption , I am using

```
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from base64 import b64decode, b64encode




def decrypt(enc):
    iv = 'mb13KcoviZizvYhp'
    key= 'TfvY7I358yospfWKcoviZizOShpm5hyH'
    text = b64decode(enc)
    value =  text[:16]
    rem = len(value) % 16
    padded = value + (b'\0' * (16 - rem)) if rem > 0 else value
    print(text , "    ", value , "      ", rem , "            ", padded)
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv,segment_size=128)
    
    return (cipher.decrypt(padded)).decode()


print((decrypt('sfYNQvBgnr5MaIA='.strip())))
```

but when I am decrypting in python, I am getting string as  `hello worldUޓY0`

can anyone please help in this???

the same thing is happening for every string,  these random characters are also completely random in length, hence slicing the result is also not an option

Comment: Padding on decryption is wrong. Use directly `text` as ciphertext. Note that a static IV is insecure.

Comment: The problem is this Golang doesn't define segment_size and always uses 128. So they apply padding always padding. You need to [unpad](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52089796/1820553)

Comment: @Topaco i have tried that , then it is giving me error that, wrong 
` ValueError: Input strings must be a multiple of the segment size 16 in length `

Comment: @kelalaka , I tried to unpad, but then i ma getting a empty response b' ' ,  can you please create a snippet for the same , it would be a great help

Comment: It must be PKCS#7 padding. Why don't you print the byte values in integer and see this?

Comment: The ciphertext is _not_ padded! This can be seen by the length: `sfYNQvBgnr5MaIA=`, which is Base64 decoded 11 bytes, i.e. equal to the plaintext size. Under Python 3 and PyCryptodome the code works if directly `text` is used as ciphertext (note that PyCryptodome doesn't de-pad implicitly). Which Python version and library do you use? Hopefully not PyCrypto. PyCrypto is legacy and buggy, and indeed has a CFB bug that requires padding. Note that, virtually all CFB implementations do _not_ require padding _regardless_ of the segment size, e.g. Golang, the Java's SunJCE provider or PyCryptodome.

Comment: thanks a lot @Topaco, before running your snippet, I have to install the PyCryptoDome first, and your solutions work perfectly. Thanks again... :)

Comment: @iron_man83 Can you provide the final working snippet. I am trying to  encrypt in golang and decrypt in python and having similar problem. Could not figure out a working solution. Thanks

Comment: Maybe @Topaco you can help and provide a working snippet ?